# How do I change the number of max_shots of Aer qasm_simulator in Qiskit running on my computer?

Tags: qiskit

I want to do a circuit with more than 1 million shots. How do I change the number of max_shots of Aer qasm_simulator in Qiskit? When I run it, it said `Number of shots specified: 1000001 exceeds max_shots property of the backend: 1000000.'`. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`backend._configuration.max_shots= ...`

Will do what you want.

Comment: Now I see why you guy put a limit to that. It takes all my RAM lol.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this parameter can be altered, I can't see a situation where you should need this many shots. You can pass more than one circuit to the execute function, so if you do `execute([qc, qc], shots=100)` each circuit will be run for 100 shots, giving you a total of 200 shots. You could use a method like this to get up to a larger number of shots if you needed.

Comment: This workaround will do, but I hope some developer here can point me out on how to  customize this.

Comment: I am a developer, you can probably update this parameter by locating this file (https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-aer/blob/81ef9533ba497bbc258c0a086691dd20384883dd/qiskit/providers/aer/backends/qasm_simulator.py) on your system and updating `max_shots`. However, as I previously said, you should not need to run things for this many shots to get an accurate idea of the probability distribution.

Comment: Oh damn, I don't mean to disrespect. Thank you, guess I'll just do the workaround, in case I break something.

Answer (score 1):

This limit is set in the configuration of the device. There is no way to edit this property as far as I know.

Comment: No I mean the Aer.qasm_simulator on my computer.